# Incredibuild not using all CPU resources , why?

Tags: cpu-usage, incredibuild

We're using Incredibuild 5 coordinator and clients.

When somebody starts a rebuild in VS2010 with Incredibuild addon, the build PC's CPU usage is not reaching 100%, just using 5-30% all time.

The build PC's clients priority settings is set to high and all cores are allocated to build processes. 
In build coordinator we using these settings:

- Build Prio: high
- Assignment prio: high
- Remote Tasks: High
- HyperThread enabled and set to max.

How can I reach the maximum CPU usage at build clients?

Answer (score 1):

These are actually good results, it means that IncrediBuild distribute your workload to other nodes very efficiently.
It is a good thing that the build machine is not too busy, the build machine is responsible for synchronizing all the output received by the remote nodes.

If you'd like to test your performance by increasing the workload on the build machine, you can increase the value that tells IncrediBuild how many cores you have on your build machine. If your machine is 8-cores hyper-threaded, IncrediBuild will only execute 8 tasks (processes) in parallel, you can instruct IncrediBuild to execute more tasks in parallel on your machine by changing the number of cores you tell IncrediBuild your machine has:
Right click the IncrediBuild tray icon->Agent Settings->Agent->CPU Utilization-> choose "user defined" in the combo box and change the value that defines the number of cores your machine has.

Pay attention, in order for IncrediBuild to consider your machine as a 16 cores machine, you should have an appropriate license. You can ask for a temporary license from your IncrediBuild account manager.

Disclaimer - I work for IncrediBuild